# \\\\r\\\\n\\\\r\\\\n Characters appearing after text inserted into a form in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a form that processes text like this:

```
$group_description = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['group_description']));

$insert_group_sql =  'INSERT INTO table_name( group_description ) 
VALUES ( "'.$group_description.'" ') ';
```

And another page that outputs the db results like this:

```
$group_description = $row['group_description'];

//Convert all urls to links
$group_description = preg_replace('#([\s|^])(www)#i', '$1http://$2', $group_description);
$pattern = '#((http|https|ftp|telnet|news|gopher|file|wais):\/\/[^\s]+)#i';
$replacement = '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>';
$group_description = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $group_description);

$group_description = str_replace(array('\r\n', '\n\r'), '<br />',$group_description);

/* Convert all E-mail matches to appropriate HTML links */
$pattern = '#([0-9a-z]([-_.]?[0-9a-z])*@[0-9a-z]([-.]?[0-9a-z])*\\.';
$pattern .= '[a-wyz][a-z](fo|g|l|m|mes|o|op|pa|ro|seum|t|u|v|z)?)#i';
$replacement = '<a href="mailto:\\1">\\1</a>';
$group_description = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $group_description);
```

What I ended up with was this page: http://www.comehike.com/hikes/hiking_group.php?hiking_group_id=54

And I am not too sure how this user got the \\r\\n characters to get in there :)

Any idea where things went wrong? I use a MySQL database if that is important.  Thanks!

Comment: The user probably pasted text with line breaks. Try using double quotes in `str_replace(array('\r\n', '\n\r')...`.

Comment: @bfavaretto Should I do that before the text is entered? Or when I am ready to display it?

Comment: And how/why would the user enter 3 back slashes before new lines as it is there? That doesn't make sense that the user really did that.

Comment: Your choice! If you cleanup the string before saving, you never have to do it again (versus before *every* display).

Comment: Good point :) but I still don't understand why there are 4 backslashes before the r's and n's.

Comment: Also, I just realized - I already have that line in the code and it doesn't work :(

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` is doing that

Comment: The line you have in the code probably doesn't work because of the single quotes. Change them to **double quotes**.

Comment: How would it be? You mean in the sql query?  Could you give an example please?

Comment: @Genadinik let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2305/discussion-between-bfavaretto-and-genadinik)

Comment: No, not the magic quotes - I checked before.

Answer (score -1):

Read up on [PHP magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php) and then think about upgrading php version.